# getting unexpected years when using date object with for loop

Tags: javascript, date

Why i'm getting unexpected years like 2021 ?

```
var dueDates = [];
var dDate = '2014-01-01';

dDate = new Date(dDate);

for (var i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {

    dDate.setMonth(i);
    dueDates.push(dDate);

}
console.log(dueDates);
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/gQ92L/

Comment: What do you expect `dDate.setMonth(18);` to do?

Comment: Bahahahahaha. 12 months total, my friend. Not 18.

Comment: I want to get 18 dates also i Set the date as 25 to all dates

Comment: @Dutchie432 lol.I know.18 is the duration of months.

Comment: @AlexWayne: It sets the month to july, and sets the year to the following year. When `setMonth` is used with values outside the 0 to 11 range, it will adjust the year accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with the code.

1. You are pushing the same Date object to the array over and over, so you will end up with an array full of references to a single Date object.
2. You are repeatedly setting the month value to values higher than 11, so that will push the years forward also. When you do `setMonth(12)` you end up at january 2015, and when you do `setMonth(13)` on that you end up at february 2016. In the end you are up to 2021.

Make a new Date object for each iteration, and set the month on that so that you always start from the same date:

```
var dueDates = [];
var dDate = '2014-01-01';

dDate = new Date(dDate);

for (var i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {

    var d = new Date(dDate.getTime());
    d.setMonth(i);
    dueDates.push(d);

}
console.log(dueDates);
```

Note: As you are starting with `setMonth(1)` that will be february. If you want to start from january you have to start from zero.